# How to fix 'Hover text to image, text keeps it's original position and img changes in background'

Tags: html, css, image, background, hover

I'm creating a webpage and was wondering when I hover over a part of text (in span) how I can keep it in it's position and make the image appear in the background, so the text can go over it.

HTML:

```
   <html>

    <link REL=StyleSheet HREF="HOVERTEST_02.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen />

    <h1>FS STUDIO</h1>

    <h2><span>Automation(FS1920)</span>.
        <img src="https://www.applerubber.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Float_Glass_Unloading.jpg"/>
    </h2>

<h2><span>Platforms(1819)</span>
    <img src="https://njmonthly.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/11/Amazon_AFradkin_4440b/1072634020.jpg"/>
</h2>
```

CSS:

```
img{
    display:none;
}

span:hover + img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    height: 600;
    width: device-width;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For image not to change the text position, you need to set `position: absolute`.

Like this, the image will ignore the other elements in the page and will let text be shown, see the quick demo above:

**UPDATED VERSION**

```css
img{
    display:none;
    width: 50vw;
    height: 40vw;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5vh;
    right: 10vw;
}

span:hover + img{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    height: 600;
    width: device-width;
    opacity: 0.8;

}
```

```html
  <h1>FS STUDIO</h1>

  <h2><span>Automation(FS1920)</span>.
      <img src="https://www.applerubber.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Float_Glass_Unloading.jpg"/>
  </h2>

<h2><span>Platforms(1819)</span>
  <img src="https://njmonthly.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/11/Amazon_AFradkin_4440b/1072634020.jpg"/>
</h2>
```

Comment: Oh ok, superb! But how do I get each image to stay in the exact same position as the one from the other link? Because now it still jumps a bit, or is that because of the image size? (trying to get something that's similar to this reference: https://saratilgaard.com/)

Comment: That's because of the height/width and also the positioning of the images, look at the updated version and I think you can work from there. just tweak the width/height for image size and top/right for image positioning :)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much, one last thing I've noticed is that the image overlays the text, is it possible for me to get the image in the background of the text when I hover?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but here is a codepen of something that looks a little more like the reference you showed: https://codepen.io/pedro-figueiredo/pen/KKPoyxZ

Comment: Thank you very much for the codepen, it's very helpful! Only thing i'm still struggling with at the moment, is that the text is only visible because the image is on 0.8 opacity. Is there any way to have the text as a 'top layer' and having the image as the secondary layer (in the back), whilst having the image at full opacity?

Comment: Sure there is, just make the z-index: -1; and it will work like a charm :) You can also take a look at the codepen, as I updated it ;)

Comment: Haha yeah I did and it worked like a charm!! Thank you so much! Lifesaver!! :D

Answer (score 0):

you mean this right?

```css
 span.one:hover{
    background-image: url('https://www.applerubber.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Float_Glass_Unloading.jpg');
   }
   span.two:hover{
    background-image: url('https://njmonthly.com/wp-content/uploads/cache/2018/11/Amazon_AFradkin_4440b/1072634020.jpg');
   }
```

```html
 <h1>FS STUDIO</h1>

    <h2><span class="one">Automation(FS1920).</span>
        
    </h2>

<h2><span class="two">Platforms(1819)</span></h2>
```

Comment: Not really, I mean something more like this reference: https://saratilgaard.com/ (I hope it's allowed to post existing works). So when you hover over a title, an image appears on a fixed position on the site.